# How to leave an open space when hiding Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, show-hide

I've been searching for a while and only came up with methods to NOT leave an open space when hiding fragments.
I have a 3-panel application and I would like that the remaining panel stay the same sizes when I hide one of them.

Here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:background="#140506">
        <fragment
            android:name="tets.twopane.FragmentA"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/titles"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
        </fragment>
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>
        <fragment
            android:name="tets.twopane.FragmentB"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewers"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
        </fragment>
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>
        <fragment
            android:name="tets.twopane.FragmentC"
            android:layout_width="0dp"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pass"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
        </fragment>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And this is the function in my main activity who hides the fragment:

```
  public void Hide3() {
    final FragmentTransaction ft = this.getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    final Fragment myFrag = this.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.pass);
    ft.hide(myFrag);
    ft.commit();

}
```

Any help will be welcomed

Answer (score 0):

I think you could probably  wrap each of your fragments with a container such as a linear layout and you can transfer the layout weight to it. So for example wrapping FragmentA this way:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <fragment
            android:name="tets.twopane.FragmentA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/titles"
            >
        </fragment>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks I think it could work that way, should have tried it.

I came up with another solution though, instead of "hiding" the fragment, i make it invisible:

  final View viewer = this.findViewById(R.id.pass);
  viewer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

It works fine